# Detecting event on Path inside a Group

Tags: javascript, canvas, frontend, fabricjs

I did quite an extensive search for people with a similar problem and even though a few got very close, I still could not find an answer to the problem itself.

I've been reading and trying different stuff from fabric.js documentation, without any success.

What I'm doing is creating 6 paths, inserting them on an array, then creating a group with this array.

The thing is that I'd like to have these 6 paths rotating a certain amount of degrees depending on which was clicked, and I managed to do that for each one of these paths.
But I'm guessing that if I'm able to rotate the entire group at once, the performance will be much better, so I'm trying without any success to rotate the Group based on which Path inside of it was clicked.

Here's the code for the individual rotating:

```
var spaceCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('spaces-canvas'),
    color = [
        '#01a4a4',
        '#7462ae',
        '#980064',
        '#d70051',
        '#e54028',
        '#e2b313'
    ],
    multiplier = 0,
    spaces = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

    var space = new fabric.Path(
        'M 0 0' +
        ' l 0 -309' +
        ' l 0 309' +
        ' l 309 -178' +
        ' l -309 -178 Z'
    );

    space.multiplier = multiplier++;
    space.active = i === 1;

    space.set({
        angle: -60 + (i * 60),
        left: 309,
        top: 309,
        fill: color[i],
        opacity: 0.5,
        perPixelTargetFind: true,
        selectable: false
    });

    spaces.push(space);

    spaceCanvas.add(space);

}

spaceCanvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {

    if (options.target.type !== 'path' || options.target.active === true) {
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < spaces.length; i++) {
        spaces[i].active = false;
        spaces[i].animate(
            'angle',
            ((spaces[i].multiplier - options.target.multiplier) - 1) * 60,
            {
                onChange: spaceCanvas.renderAll.bind(spaceCanvas)
            }
        );
    }

    options.target.active = true;

    spaceCanvas.renderAll();
});
```

http://codepen.io/arthurgouveia/pen/nDJaK

Aside from that, I'm not sure why once clicked the Path is getting the bounding box to show up. I might be forgetting something or doing something wrong.

If anyone would help me out or just lead me on the correct path to rotate the Group instead of each Path, would be awesome.

Thanks a lot in advance.

ps.: let me know if you'd like to see what I tried with the Group approach.

Comment: FYI, I found out how to disable the bounding boxes, by setting hasControls: false, hasBorders: false on the paths.

Still no clue how to rotate the group instead of individually each Path. Just tested on a VM with IE8 and it's resulting in delays that make the rotating Paths intersect each other.

Comment: Can you show what you tried with the Group approach?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to do this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hyCdD based on your code, and I used http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html, don't know if it's ok for your purpose. If you want to access the items in Group, try `wheel.item(0)...`

```
var spaceCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('spaces-canvas'),
    color = [
        '#01a4a4',
        '#7462ae',
        '#980064',
        '#d70051',
        '#e54028',
        '#e2b313'
    ],
    multiplier = 0,
    spaces = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

    var space = new fabric.Path(
        'M 0 0' +
        ' l 0 -309' +
        ' l 0 309' +
        ' l 309 -178' +
        ' l -309 -178 Z'
    );

    space.multiplier = multiplier++;
    space.active = i === 1;

    space.set({
        angle: -60 + (i * 60),
        left: 309,
        top: 309,
        fill: color[i],
        opacity: 0.5,
        perPixelTargetFind: true,
        selectable: false,
        hasControls: false,
        hasBorders: false
    });

    spaces.push(space);


}

var wheel = new fabric.Group (spaces, {      
    left : 300,
    top: 200,
    originX: "center",
    originY: "center",
});

wheel.hasControls = false;
wheel.hasBorders = false;

spaceCanvas.add(wheel);
spaceCanvas.renderAll();

spaceCanvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {

    if (options.target.type !== 'path' || options.target.active === true) 
    {
        //return;
    }

    wheel.animate(
      'angle', 
      wheel.angle + 60, 
      {
        onChange: spaceCanvas.renderAll.bind(spaceCanvas)
    });

    return;

});
```